How to add modified field dependency i.e in case of custom object and custom picklist fields....to outbound change set in salesforce?
How to add modified field dependency i.e in case of custom object and custom picklist fields....to outbound change set in salesforce?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I modified existing field dependency and i woud like to deploy through change set .. how we can add to change set.. is it enough to add  controlling and dependency fields to changeset or is there any other option to add

As you've surmised in your comment, simply adding the fields that had their dependencies modified should be sufficient for the change set. Strictly speaking, I believe you only need the dependent picklist field, because how the dependency metadata is presented in the Metadata API, but it wouldn't hurt to include both the controlling and dependent fields to be certain you don't miss anything.

Thank you so much .
